# 'Invalid IPA: the .app must be in a "Payload" (case-sensitive) folder.'

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

Application Loader 2.9.1 / XCode 5.1.1 Mac Os X 10.8.5

I have a .ipa and tried to upload it through Application Loader but I got this error :

> IPA is invalid, it does not include a payload directory.

What can I do ?

Comment: I had this error and uploaded a second time my app and it worked fine.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Make sure the key "LSRequiresIPhoneOS" in the info.plist has the value "YES"

Comment: Just looking at it... its at YES. i tried with the command line tools : xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication -v "/Users/patvicto/adophone/platforms/ios/AdoPhonique.app" -o \
 "/Users/patvicto/adophone/platforms/ios/adophonique-ios-test-1.ipa" \
 --sign "iPhone Distribution: Patrick Simard (35VA493W3P)" \
 --embed "/Users/patvicto/Desktop/Apple/AdoPhonique2014.mobileprovision"  no error the package is valid sign on disk , but again the same error when sending with Application Loader...

Comment: And make sure it's LSRequiresIPhoneOS, *not* LSRequiresIphoneOS with a lower case p in iPhone. My Plists had that, which used to work until XCode 6, but now this is apparently required. (Well, not to build or archive, but to add AdHoc builds to iTunes or submit AppStore builds to Apple)

Comment: This worked for me.  Was updating a very old app -- not sure if / how this was set to NO. 'requires iPhone iOS environment' was set to NO.

Comment: After adding the key, Clean the project!

Comment: Added the key, you can also find it under "Application requires iPhone environment", cleaned the project, CMD + B for new build and afterwards the archive was valid. Great!

Comment: As per my answer, just added, if you have to add this key manually, because it doesn't exist, then the value is `true`, not `YES`.

Comment: UPDATE: if you have any value in "LSRequiresIPhoneOS" now iTunes Connect will reject you

Answer (score 13):

Make sure the key “Application requires iPhone environment” Value is YES

in the info.plist

Like this http://xcode5.tistory.com/entry/iOS-The-IPA-is-invalid-it-does-not-include-a-Payload-directory

Answer (score 2):

I faced same issue, but I resolved by doing three things:

1. check in your plist file this key exist `CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion` and it value should be 6.0
2. check your icon file and icon files key in plist and they have all icons of your game that support iOS 7, please check all icon should have extension .png
3. check your 3rd party sdk that included in your project in right way or not. my project has problem with revmoe also

Comment: icone file ? In ressources/icons/  i got those images : icon-40.png,icon-40@2x.png,icon-50.png,icon-50@2x.png,icon-60.png,icon-60@2x.png,icon-72.png,icon-72@2x.png,icon-76.png,icon-76@2x.png,icon-small.png,icon-small@2x.png and icon.png , icon@2x.png.

Comment: And sure enough , all the splash (7 different ones formats).

Answer (score 0):

Open your Info.plist file and click plus(+) and write Info Dictionary Version which is 6.0 and clean app and upload it Again. now you get clear Idea.

Note: Make iPa file to .Zip format and try again.

Comment: Looked at my info.plist and this is the version i have : 6.0. Tried lots to upload from Application Loader 2.9.1 always says the same error message.  I built the application from XCode   Product build (destination iOs device) and did "product ... Archive" also. The application is fully signed with profile and all needed just cant' get what is missing to be a fully "valid" one.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution for some, worked for me...

I struggled with this for a couple hours, tried several different things that I found through researching all the different solutions people have posted online, but nothing worked. I then went into "edit scheme", then into the "info" section under "run" and found that the "Build configuration" option was set to "debug." I thought this to be odd, so I changed it to "release", and validation finally worked!

I had recently submitted an update a couple weeks earlier, and everything worked fine. I had added localizations to this new update, but didn't see anything that may have caused things in the project to go wrong. I noticed that since my last update though (only two weeks ago) some of my project's data had been automatically reverted back to the first version of the app. For example, my version code was set to 1.0, but the last update was 1.3. Also, my build version went back to 1, but should have been 4. I don't know why this happened, but it did, and I'm guessing that this automatic revert perhaps changed my build configuration also, causing the "IPA invalid" "No payload" error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In the target project - Build Settings - Packaging. You should verify that the path is correct info.plist.
Once linked, clean the project and compile

Answer (score 0):

A couple of answers here are both "right", but took a bit of pondering for me to figure out how to actually implement - I'm no "plist guru".

If you already have `Application requires iPhone environment` in the GUI in xcode, then `Cruz JWK`'s answer is an easy no-brainer: just toggle it to YES.

But what if you don't?

"ecume des jours" says, succinctly

> Make sure the key "LSRequiresIPhoneOS" in the info.plist has the
>   value "YES"

But how?

It turns out that the answer is like this:

```
<key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
<true/>
```

Once you put this in your plist file, suddenly you will have `Application requires iPhone environment` in your xcode settings, and it will be `Boolean: YES`.

The link between "make it YES" and "set the key to `<true/>`" wasn't obvious to me.  I started with setting it as `<string>YES<string/>`, which didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when i archived through xcode 6 and exported through xcode 5.1.1 (Exporting through xcode 6 requires team/account info). Later using xcode 6.3 for both purposes fixed my issue.

**Note:** When i tried the plist solutions, it was already there and error was keeping coming.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and tried many answers from internet and non worked. Then I searched Apple documentation files and came across this link.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/UploadingYourApptoiTunesConnect/UploadingYourApptoiTunesConnect.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH36-SW2

Basically do the code signing and build your App against a device and then you go to "Product -> Archives"  in Xcode menu and from there you validate the package and use the upload button there to upload your bundle to App store.

Hope this helps.

All this time I used Application uploader and this is the first time I am using Archives to submit my app as described in the above Apple's guide.

Xcode 7.

Answer (score -2):

That means that you don't have application in iTunes connect with "Prepare for Submission" status.
Check iTunes Connect