# How do I update my app on app store?Keep getting Payload error

Tags: ios, app-store, ios-app-group

I have gone through the entire application process and it is definitely very tiring and hectic. I keep getting "Invalid .ipa , the app must be in payload" error. I exhausted all the possible solutions for the fix to no avail, tried changing CFBundleversion/set the lsiphoneenvironment to yes.I just don't know how to regenerate the .ipa file? Is there a way I can delete it and regenerate it completely afresh? I have everything set in my app store, just this one step is blocking me as I can't upload the binaries or push an update.Any possible solutions besides one listed here will be awesome:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25859054/invalid-ipa-the-app-must-be-in-a-payload-case-sensitive-folder
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution lies in the new option in Xcode 5 which says provisioning profile. Just set the project target's provisioning profile to the right one and it'll work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can  resolved by doing three things

1- check in your plist file this key exist CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion and it value should be 6.0

2- check your icon file and icon files key in plist and they have all icons of your game that support ios 7, please check all icon should have extention .png

3- check your 3rd party sdk that included in your project in right way or not. my project has problem with revmob also

// ******* OR ************//

Check iTunes Connect that  you don't have application in iTunes connect with "Prepare for Submission" status.

Happy Coding .. :)